# Where or how I might be able to find low hanging fruit in applied category theory?

Tags: category-theory, applications, publishing

If anyone happens to know, can you please give me an idea of (or where to look for) what could be low hanging fruit for an applied category theory paper for someone with down time between undergrad and grad school?  This could be problem(s) to solve, unexplored territory to map out, code to write, or whatever.

For what it's worth, I’m trying to get some background in computer science (particularly data science) in the tech scene in SF, before applying to the mathematics and foundations of computer science masters at Oxford. (But, I'm interested in just about anything category theory could be applied to.)

I have read a ton.  But as far as actually working problems, I have bounced around some books, but will complete Spivak and Fong’s new book on applied category theory in the next month or so (every problem).

Also, if this isn't the right place to ask this, or if my tags are not good (or anything else), can you please let me know what to do instead?

Thanks,